# Is there a model that explains why Italy is the second most affected country by COVID-19?

Tags: virus, epidemiology, covid-19

I'm wondering if there's a model which explains why Italy is currently, judging by the data, the second most affected country by COVID-19. I'm not only talking about deaths but also infections.

It seems somewhat strange to me, considering that no other countries I'm aware of implemented any measure against the virus in the early days after the news was made public in China, also considering the virus may as well been circulating for some time already. 
It also seems unlikely that Italy is more connected to China than other countries are.

One simple explanation I cannot entirely buy tho, is that other countries are not testing as thoroughly and therefore they are underestimating the risk.

Comment: I don't think a model is really necessary - there doesn't have to be any difference between Italy and other countries. Epidemics like this tend to spread at random around particular cases; in Italy, it seems like it spread a bit while undetected, probably mostly among people who had only mild symptoms not differentiated from other similar illnesses often experienced this time of year. Probably the same thing happened in Washington in the US, and to some extent in South Korea.

Comment: the virus appears to be a cold season virus so it's likely to affect countries more in their cold seasons.